# Also show the meta accounts on the user's profile page

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, per-site-meta

When I look at the accounts listed at a "users"-page ([example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen?tab=accounts)), I do not see any of the meta accounts – not even when on **meta**.tex.stackexchange.com, at my own users-page, and choosing "view more":

[image: example profile with suggestion for meta data placement]

While meta does not have its own reputation but inherits it from the main page, the "last seen", "badges", "questions", and "answers" are meta-specific.

Could this information be added to the users page, please? I added an example in the image above.

Comment: I think that would be way too much clutter. How do you propose these are sorted?

Comment: @slhck: The badges and Q&As could be showed direct below the main-site values. Below the reputation there could be a "Meta:" to indicate that the second row are for the related meta account.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: +1, yes, one line would be sufficient, does not have to be bold and can even have a smaller font size or grey instead of black colour. After the "last seen" entries there is about 75% of a line which is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this suggestion, but don't think showing just the meta badges serves any purpose other than padding one's badge display. Instead of just "Meta", it could show something like `Q: 15/60, A: 50/200`, where the first number in each is the number of Q/A and the second number is the net votes total. This shows the user's participation at a glance and you can get a quick sense of which communities they're active in (other than asking/answering). This is the same format used to show a candidate's meta participation in the elections (here's an example from the recent SO election)

[image]

Showing just the badges is useless, as the gold and silver that you have there could be for `Fanatic` and `Enthusiast` respectively, which are useless and tell me nothing about your participation.

Comment: "there could be for Fanatic and Enthusiast respectively" In my case they are indeed, but what I personally are interested in is the "last seen" information. Just thought: Why not add all/the same information as for the main account? (At least when viewing ones own site - does not even have to be public visible.)

Comment: So what is the purpose of showing the non-meta badges?